# Removing Sub Directory

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite 
domainname/abc/def.php

to 
domainname/xyz/

Solving in this way:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^xyz/$ /abc/def.php [L]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I tested your RewriteRule and it worked. It may be an apache configuration issue. For example, you are using .htaccess but AllowOverride is set to None in apache configuraion.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am looking into the matter.